# Need to impersonate User in Jenkins

Tags: authentication, jenkins, single-sign-on

I am working on a project where a user will be redirected from an internal website to Jenkins. The jenkins is configured for LDAP Authentication. The internal website has already authenticated user. My objective is to impersonate that user in Jenkins without asking for credentials.

Possible approaches and their issues:

1. I don't want to use Kerberos SSO
2. Jenkins supports Authentication via User's API Token. For this method, Jenkins expects AUthorization header with username:ApiToken(Base64 encoded). But, since I am redirecting user from internal website to Jenkins, I cannot set that header. Somehow, I couldn't find any way of setting headers via javascript before redirecting.
3. I wrote a Filter in Jenkins that added Authorization header in request. I tried passing auth credentials via GET Parameter to Jenkins. My Filter converted this GET Parameter to Authorization header in HTTPServletRequest.
   But that didn't work. Jenkins didn't authenticate that user.

Possible rootcause: 
I looked up Jenkins's source code and found BasicProcessingFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter. I think that these filters are being called before my Filter. So, at essence I am trying to add Authorization Header after Authentication Filters. So, my attempts failed.

Currently, I am blocked and cannot figure out any way out.

Note: I do have access to user's API Token in Jenkins.

Please help.

Comment: Keep an eye on this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18453